# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema, joi

I have the following setup in Visual Studio Code for nodejs project:

Model: genre.js

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const genreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
      type:String,
      required:true,
      minlength:5,
      maxlength:50
  }
});

const Genre = mongoose.model('Genre',genreSchema);

function validateGenre(genre) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
    };

    return Joi.validate(genre, schema);
}

exports.genreSchema = genreSchema;
exports.Genre = Genre;
exports.validate = validateGenre;
```

movie.js:

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { genreSchema } = require('./genre');

const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 255
    },
    genre: {
        type: genreSchema,
        required: true
    },
    numberInStock: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 255
    },
    dailyRentalRate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 255
    }
}));

function validateMovie(movie) {
    const schema = {
        title: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required,
        genreId: Joi.string().required,
        numberInStock: Joi.number().min(0).required,
        dailyRentalRate: Joi.number().min(0).required
    };

    return Joi.validate(movie,schema);
}

exports.Movie = Movie;
exports.validate = validateMovie;
```

routes: movies.js

```
const { Movie, validate } = require('../models/movie');
const { Genre } = require('../models/genre');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const movies = await Movie.find().sort('name');
    res.send(movies);
});

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!movie) return res.status(404).send('The movie with the given Id was not found');
    res.send(movie);
});

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    const genre = await Genre.findById(req.body.genreId);
    if (!genre) return res.status(404).send('Invalid genre.');

    let movie = new Movie({
        title: req.body.title,
        genre: {
            _id: genre._id,
            name: genre.name
        },
        numberInStock: req.body.numberInStock,
        dailyRentalRate: req.body.dailyRentalRate
    });

    movie = await movie.save();
    res.send(movie);
});

router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    const genre = await Genre.findById(req.body.genreId);
    if (!genre) return res.status(404).send('Invalid genre.');

    const movie = await Movie.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        title: req.body.title,
        genre: {
            _id: genre._id,
            name: genre.name
        },
        numberInStock: req.body.numberInStock,
        dailyRentalRate: req.body.dailyRentalRate
    }, { new: true });

    if (!movie) return res.status(404).send('The movie with the given ID was not found.');
    res.send(movie);
});

router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const movie = await Movie.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
    if (!movie) return res.status(404).send('The movie with the given ID was not found.');
    res.send(movie);
});

module.exports = router;
```

On trying to create a movie with the following setup :

[image]

I am getting an error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this issue

Comment: Its required(), but not required I guess

Comment: I corrected required to required() and it works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

first, the Joi.validate(genre, schema) is an outdated built-in function try doing something like this:

```
function validateGenre(genre) {
const schema = joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
});

  return schema.validate(genre);
}
```

And also in your validateMovie function, you need to add () next to the required e.g

```
function validateMovie(movie){
    const shema = joi.object({
    name: joi.string().max(10).min(5).required();
});
  return shema.validate(movie);
```

}